# Local space radiation measurement by 1U CubeSat

Tags: artificial-satellite, cubesat

As far as I know, the general influx of ionizing radiation received by a CubeSat in LEO is mostly trapped protons and electrons, solar protons, galactic cosmic radiation, and
neutrons. If the CubeSat is equipped with a *readable dosimeter*, it is possible to monitor where and how much radiation hit the electronic devices during the course of the satellite. The data collected can then be sent as part of a *downlink data stream*.

**My Question is:** How particles of solar radiation and galactic cosmic particles detected? How is it possible to differentiate them from the general influx of radiation received by a dosimeter? What kind of instruments are necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure if "the general influx of radiation" has a well-defined meaning, and what is left over after you subtract "particles of solar radiation and galactic cosmic particle".  [Dosimeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosimeter) try measure [dose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert) independent of cause, particle type, direction, etc. If you want to *distinguish* different types of ionizing radiation instead of lumping all their doses together, then you'll need two or more different kinds of [particle detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_detector).